# Изморось и изморозь

Tags: лексика

Так до конца и не могу определиться: оба ли эти слова имеют право на существование? По логике, изморозь — это легким морозец, а изморось — мелкий невнятный дождь. Но, может, я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Изморозь — это не легкий морозец, а серебристый снежный слой от этого морозца, оседающий на любых поверхностях - крышах, деревьях и т.д., -а изморось(морось) - мелкий дождь. Так и проверяем: изморозь - морозит, изморось - моросит.

Answer (score 1):

Изморозь - от "морозит", изморось - от "моросит". Оба  слова имеют полное право на существование.

Answer (score -1):

Изморозь — взвесь очень мелких кристаллов льда (снега) в газе, уменьшающая его прозрачность, изморось = очень мелкий, моросящий дождь.

Comment: Ну вы просто повторили утрерждение из вопроса. А добавить-то по существу что-нибудь?

Comment: Хорошо бы сослаться на источник (источники) знаний...